# How do you call a function stored in a variable within Python,mh

Tags: python, function, variables, authentication

Below as you can see when I try to call the `mainLogin()` function stored in a variable it says it has not been defined.

I know there's a way around but cant seem to figure it out.

```
validUser = {}
answer = ""

answer = mainLogin()

def mainLogin():
    while True:
        print("Are you currently a registered user [y/n]: ")
        answer = input().lower()
        if answer in "y n".split():
            return answer
        else:
            print("Error: please enter [y/n].")

def Login(answer):
    if answer == "y":
        while True:
            askUsername = input("ENTER USERNAME: ")
            askPassword = input("ENTER PASSWORD: ")
            if len(askUsername) > 0 and askUsername.isalpha():
                if askUsername in validUser and valid[askUsername] == askPassword:
                    print("\nLogin Success!\n")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Error: Incorrect username or password!")
            else:
                print("Error: Don't be silly!")
    elif answer == "n":
        while True:
            createUsername = input("ENTER NEW USERNAME: ")
            if len(createUsername) > 0 and createUsername.isalpha():
                if createrUsername in validUser:
                    print("Meesage: username already exists.")
                else:
                    createPassword = input("ENTER NEW PASSWORD: ")
                    if len(createPassword) > 0 and createPasssword.isalpha():
                        validUser[createUsername] == createPassword
                        print("\nUSER CREATED\n")
                    else:
                        print("Error: Please choose a different password.")
            else:
                print("Error: Don't be silly!")
    else:
        print("Error: You have not entered [y/n]")
```

Comment: Move the line to *below* the point you define the function object. Python executes statements line by line.

Comment: At the time `mainLogin()` is called you haven't `def`ined `mainLogin()`. Move it to after the function definition.

Comment: In `php` you can assign a function before declaring it, this doesn't work in `python`, move `answer = mainLogin()` below the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `answer = mainLogin()` and the bottom of your file.

The functions below have not yet been registered by python.
Python will go thought your script/module line by line. When you have code in the root of the module it will be executed.

To solve this problem you can also do the following:

```
def main():
    answer = mainLogin()

def mainLogin():
    # code

if __name__ = "__main__":
    main()
```

Here python will inspect the entire file from top to bottom before we start doing any work. This is the standard way to solve the problem.

`__name__` is the name of the module. It will be assigned the name `__main__` if we specifically start the module with the python command. `python script.py`. If we import the module from another script, `__name__` will contain the actual name of the module, so `main()` will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a function that isn't defined to a variable, first you define the function, then you assign it to the variable. Like this:

```
def mainLogin():
    while True:
        print("Are you currently a registered user [y/n]: ")
        answer = input().lower()
        if answer in "y n".split():
            return answer
        else:
            print("Error: please enter [y/n].")

answer = mainLogin()
```